# Podfile Problem? Use of unresolved identifier 'Auth' -

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods

I'm getting error

> "Use of unresolved identifier 'Auth'" in two of my viewControllers.

I've tried reinstalling the `PodFiles` and updating the `dependencies`. I've also tried updating to the latest version of everything, and have closed and shutdown `Xcode` many times.

**My PodFile includes:**

> pod 'Firebase/Auth'
>    pod 'Firebase/Core'
>    pod 'Firebase/Database'

I've also imported the following into the `AppDelegate`:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: Any) {

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!) { (user, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToHome", sender: self)
            }
        }
     }
}
```

To remove the code.

Comment: Make sure you have opened the `workspace` and not the `xcode project`.

Comment: Try building the project

Comment: Opened --- ProjectGensis11.xcworkspace , as I have been doing and I'm still having th e issue.

Comment: Hit 'command + R' and received a "Build Failed" error.

Comment: Try deleting the pod and installing it again.
"pod deintegrate" and then "pod install". If that doesn't work, try "pod update" to see if it's the version.

Comment: I tried both. The error is still persistent.

Comment: @WindGravity In Project->Target->Build Settings->Active Architecture set it to `NO` here and for `Pod` -> Target -> Build Settings here as well.